# TBODY background-image gets improperly applied to all TD elements too, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, background-image, html-table

A TBODY background-image declared in CSS is being applied to **all** TD elements in the TBODY, expected to be applied to just the TBODY.

To reproduce: create a table with multiple tbody each containing some rows and cells. Declare a TBODY background image with CSS. The result I expect is the TBODY should display a single image as the background. However in Chrome, Safari, Opera see that the background image is *repeated* for each TD in the TBODY as well (tested on Mac, most recent browser versions as of this post date). It renders as expected in FireFox on Mac and OK on Edge on Win10 too.

In the sample code I expect the backgroung image (a 6px wide black bar) to display in the 1,2 and 4th TBODY and not the 3rd. This happens but see that the black bar background image is applied to the TD elements as well, which is not good. This is not expected behavior as I want the background image to be on the left side of the TBODY container element.

Is there a workaround for this? The TBODY is the element I want to leverage as this allows for a single declaration for a defined background image to span all the rows in the tbody, makes it nice and logical.

This does appear to be a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35697

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acyeheq6/

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
tbody.tb1 { background-color: lightblue; }
tbody.tb2 { background-color: lightgray; }
tbody td { padding-left: 15px; }
tbody.item {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/6x80/000/fff.png);
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<table>  
  <tbody class="item tb1">
    <tr>
      <td>6/22/16</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Temporibus autem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="item tb2">
    <tr>
      <td>6/19/16</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Temporibus autem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Finibus Bonorum et Malorum</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="tb1">
    <tr>
      <td>6/18/16</td>
      <td>Expedita distinctio</td>
      <td>Deserunt mollitia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">Doloribus asperiores repellat.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="item tb2">
    <tr>
      <td>6/17/16</td>
      <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
      <td>Temporibus autem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">similique sunt in culpa qui officia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obligatory "I can't believe it even works in Microsoft Edge" remark.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of `background-image` in `<tbody>` in Chrome.
So, I think you may change your method to achieving the target.

As you described:

> In the sample code I expect the backgroung image (a 6px wide black bar) to display in the 1,2 and 4th TBODY and not the 3rd.

And:

> FireFox on Mac and OK on Edge on Win10

Not add background image in `<tbody>`, just add it in first `<td>` element of each rows.

**Solution:**  Changing CSS selector `tbody.item` into `tbody.item > tr > td:first-child`